# Cookie are not saving

Tags: c#, reactjs, rest, cookies

I am trying to develop REST API for my reactJS app, but I faced with problem during implementing the authorization. My post request (code below) is actually working, I checked it with adding few breakpoints, and responses with code 200. But cookie seems not to save. Even after post method successful completion, get method returns code 401 (not authorized). Also I want to notice that everything is working fine if requests are sent not from client, but from server app directly (using swagger, as example). So here is the code of reactJS:

```
// this method will be called when button is pressed
login = (login, password) => {
        axios
            .post(`https://localhost:7072/auth/login?Login=${login}&Password=${password}`, { withCredentials: true })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    //window.location.href = '/profile';
                    console.log(response);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        // GET request here (always returns code 401)
    }
```

C# get/post methods:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/auth/login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromQuery]LoginUser request)
    {
        var user = users
            .FirstOrDefault(x => 
                x.Login == request.Login &&
                x.Password == request.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "Wrong login or password");
        }
        
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Login),
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, "Success");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/auth/get")]
    public IActionResult GetUser()
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, "User is not authenticated");
        }

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, User.Identity!.Name);
    }
```

program.cs config:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowLocalhost3000",
        config =>
        {
            config.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                .WithExposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("AllowLocalhost3000");

// ...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

//...
```

The last thing I tried was editing CORS policy config, but this only helped with successful sending request to the server. Now I don't even know what to try to get rid of this problem. Rely on your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Is your C# server running on HTTPS or is it running on HTTP? Because your axios request is trying to use HTTPS.

Comment: It runs on HTTPS. As I already mentioned, server responds, it returns success after post request. The thing is cookies are not saving